# Nvim command - "Grep >"

Tags: grep, neovim

I'm having trouble with the "Grep >" command in nvim I'm testing nvim and im trying to do a Grep > search but its not working i am viewing my file and i have the word requires in it but when i try to do Grep > requires it does not show anything can anyone help me with this?[search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj7Z6.png) [grep >](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjV5f.png)

thank you in advanced

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[BurntSushi/ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is required for live_grep and grep_string.